# SQL Update First Table With a Conditional Variable Retrival in Second Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update `statusId` of `T1` table via the following logic.

`update t1.statusId with (t2.statusId where t2.statusName = closed)
where t1.RecordId = 999`

Below is my current query:

```
UPDATE 
    [DB].[T1]

SET
    [DB].[T1].StatusId = t1.StatusId

FROM
    [DB].[T1] t1

LEFT JOIN [DB].[T2] t2
    ON t1.StatusId = t2.StatusId

WHERE t1.RecordId= 999

AND t2.StatusName = 'Closed'
```

**Q:** Query is unable to locate this particular record in `T1` to update as currently it is of a `statusId` other than the `statusId` of `Closed`.

I think my `join` query is wrong, and I should be taking `AND t2.StatusName='Closed'` out to be processed in another way.

Comment: OK, so what's wrong? What is your question?

Comment: updated my post. my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `join`, but it looks like this:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET StatusId = t2.StatusId
FROM [DB].[T1] t1 JOIN
     [DB].[T2] t2
     ON t1.RecordId = 999 AND
        t2.StatusName = 'Closed';
```

Or:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET StatusId = t2.StatusId
FROM [DB].[T1] t1 CROSS JOIN
     [DB].[T2] t2
WHERE t1.RecordId = 999 AND
      t2.StatusName = 'Closed';
```

(The two are identical.)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're after is this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET StatusID = (SELECT T2.StatusId FROM [SCHEMA].T2 WHERE T2.StatusName = 'Closed')
FROM [SCHEMA].T1 T1
WHERE T1.RecordId = 999;
```

You were joining onto `T2` using the current status of the row in `T1`, which meant you would only update the rows that are already closed, to closed; making it a fruitless update.

(I used a different name for the objects (well schema) as `[DB].[T1]` is confusing. As `DB` would be a schema, not a database, and these are clearly anonymised object names.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE [DB].[T1]
SET StatusId = (
    SELECT StatusId
    FROM [DB].[T2]
    WHERE StatusName = 'Closed'
)
WHERE RecordId= 999
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try like below,

```
UPDATE [DB].[T1]
SET StatusId = (
    SELECT top 1 StatusId
    FROM [DB].[T2]
    WHERE StatusName = 'closed'
)
WHERE RecordId= 999
```

Note:- You should select top 1 in the sub query ,else it may return multiple records and you will get error.